# Ruby - fetch image from URL and convert it to text

Tags: ruby, http, ocr

I need to fetch images from a website and parse the text on it in Ruby.

The images are very simple, they're just digits represented in picture form:

http://www.telelistas.net/ImgFactory.ashx?t=6A7B&s=0

Using this example, I'd like to convert this picture to the text "56".

Answer (score 2):

What you need is something do OCR. Looks https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract is pretty promising.  You can convert an image to a text like :

```
image = RTesseract.new("my_image.jpg")
image.to_s #Getting the value
```

Comment: I looked into this library, but I couldn't get it to load a picture from a URL and when I tested it loading the picture I wanted from the local filesystem, it raised a ConversionError.

Answer (score 1):

Load from URL implies a cloud-based Web-based OCR service, such as [www.OCR-IT.com](http://www.OCR-IT.com).  Other Web-based services also should be able to open from URL.  Alternatively, if you are interested to develop your own OCR conversion tool, such as using Tesseract, then most likely the 'open from URL' functionality needs to be added separately, which is doable.  Ultimately, running your own OCR will means downloading images to local storage at some point transparent to the process.  That is not a bad option, considering it is necessary for some image pre-processing.

Aside from that, there are a few issues with your image sample, which will affect any OCR system:

- resolution is too low.  You may need to artificially blow up the resolution.
- size is too small (related to above).  You may need to artificially expand the picture.
- GIF is not OCR-friendly format.
- Resolution and metadata is missing in headers, unlike in TIF/PNG/JPG

For example, ABBYY FineReader 8.0 desktop applicaiton (world's best commercial OCR) cannot extract the text from your sample in as-is form.